# Rewriting a statement using Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I need to write the statement

> The product of a rational number and an irrational number is irrational.

into a statement using quantifiers. I am also supposed to state the domain of discourse for both x and y. Here's what I have so far:

> ∀ xϵQ yϵR∖Q (irrational numbers) P((x*y)→y))

I doubt the last section with (x*y)=>y is correct. Is this statement accurate?

Comment: It's not clear what $P$ means in your proof.    Instead, go with $\forall x \in \mathbb Q,  y\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q (x\cdot y \in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q).  Else, @quasi has a nice, and perhaps simpler statement, *provided we specify that the domain of discourse* is the set of real numbers, which is the union:  = \mathbb Q U \mathbb Q^c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the domain of discourse.

Let $Q(t)$ be the statement that $t$ is rational.

Then the given statement can be fomulated as
$$\forall x,y \;(Q(x) \land \lnot Q(y)) \rightarrow (\lnot Q(xy))$$

As a point of interest, the statement is actually false, since if $x=0$, then for any irrational $y$, the hypothesis will be true, but the conclusion will be false. However, the question was just to model the statement, not to analyze its truth value.

Comment: AvenNova  This is a very nice way to prove what you're asking to prove.  **Key points:** (1) The *domain* in which x, y, t, or any variable reside is in the set of real numbers.  Also, note the use of the predicate $Q(t)$: "t" is rational.  Then $\lnot Q(t)$ means that "t is not rational," (and since the domain is restricted to the Real numbers, it means "t is irrational."

Comment: Definitely get it now, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving in smaller steps.

First, write an intermediate statement with quantifiers and some english language remaining:

- $\forall x \in Q$, $y \in R \setminus Q$, the product of $x$ and $y$ is irrational.

Next, translate into a little more math and a little less English:

- $\forall x \in Q$, $y \in R \setminus Q$, $x*y$ is irrational.

Next, translate into all math and no English:

- $\forall x \in Q$, $y \in R \setminus Q$, $x*y \in R \setminus Q$

So your doubt is on the mark.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!